# Test for import of optional dependencies in __init__.py with pytest: Python 3.5 /3.6 differs in behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.6, pytest

I have a package for python 3.5 and 3.6 that has optional dependencies for which I want tests (pytest) that run on either version.

I made a reduced example below consisting of two files, a simple `__init__.py` where the optional package "requests" (just an example) is imported and a flag is set to indicate the availability of requests.

```
mypackage/
├── mypackage
│   └── __init__.py
└── test_init.py
```

The `__init__.py` file content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

requests_available = True

try:
    import requests
except ImportError:
    requests_available = False
```

The `test_init.py` file content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pytest, sys

def test_requests_missing(monkeypatch):
    import mypackage
    import copy
    fakesysmodules = copy.copy(sys.modules)
    fakesysmodules["requests"] = None
    monkeypatch.delitem(sys.modules,"requests")
    monkeypatch.setattr("sys.modules", fakesysmodules)
    from importlib import reload
    reload(mypackage)
    assert mypackage.requests_available == False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([__file__, "-vv", "-s"])
```

The `test_requests_missing` test works on Python 3.6.5:

```
runfile('/home/bjorn/python_packages/mypackage/test_init.py', wdir='/home/bjorn/python_packages/mypackage')
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /home/bjorn/anaconda3/envs/bjorn36/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/bjorn/python_packages/mypackage, inifile:
plugins: requests-mock-1.5.0, mock-1.10.0, cov-2.5.1, nbval-0.9.0, hypothesis-3.38.5
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_init.py::test_requests_missing PASSED

=========================== 1 passed in 0.02 seconds ===========================
```

But not on Python 3.5.4:

```
runfile('/home/bjorn/python_packages/mypackage/test_init.py', wdir='/home/bjorn/python_packages/mypackage')
========================================================= test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.4, pytest-3.6.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /home/bjorn/anaconda3/envs/bjorn35/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/bjorn/python_packages/mypackage, inifile:
plugins: requests-mock-1.5.0, mock-1.10.0, cov-2.5.1, nbval-0.9.1, hypothesis-3.38.5
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_init.py::test_requests_missing FAILED

=============================================================== FAILURES ===============================================================
________________________________________________________ test_requests_missing _________________________________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f9a2953acc0>

    def test_requests_missing(monkeypatch):
        import mypackage
        import copy
        fakesysmodules = copy.copy(sys.modules)
        fakesysmodules["requests"] = None
        monkeypatch.delitem(sys.modules,"requests")
        monkeypatch.setattr("sys.modules", fakesysmodules)
        from importlib import reload
>       reload(mypackage)

test_init.py:13: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../anaconda3/envs/bjorn35/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py:166: in reload
    _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:626: in _exec
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:697: in exec_module
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:222: in _call_with_frames_removed
    ???
mypackage/__init__.py:8: in <module>
    import requests
../../anaconda3/envs/bjorn35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:97: in <module>
    from . import utils

.... VERY LONG OUTPUT ....

    from . import utils
../../anaconda3/envs/bjorn35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:97: in <module>
    from . import utils
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:968: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:953: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:896: in _find_spec
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1171: in find_spec
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1145: in _get_spec
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1273: in find_spec
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1245: in _get_spec
    ???
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

name = 'requests', location = '/home/bjorn/anaconda3/envs/bjorn35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'

>   ???
E   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:575: RecursionError
======================================================= 1 failed in 2.01 seconds =======================================================
```

I have two questions:

1. Why do I see this difference? Relevant packages seem to be of the same version on both 3.5 and 3.6.
2. Is there a better way to do what I want? The code I have now is stitched together from examples found online. I have tried to patch the import mechanism in an attempt to avoid "reload", but I have not managed.

Comment: That's a thoughtful question. Here are just a couple of suggestions. First, elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish with `test_requests_missing`, as this seems to be quite hacky. Second, you can narrow down the problem by minimizing the function (according to your intent) and also by using `pipenv`: prepare a minimal `Pipfile`, create a virtual env for different Python versions (with small steps, i.e., including `3.6.0`, `3.6.1` and so on), find out the Python version where you code stops working, and peruse release notes for the version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write unittests for an optional dependency in a python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916040/how-to-write-unittests-for-an-optional-dependency-in-a-python-package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would either mock the [`__import__` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) (the one invoked behind the `import modname` statement), or customize the import mechanism by adding a custom meta path finder. Examples:

#### Altering `sys.meta_path`

Add a custom [`MetaPathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder) implementation that raises an `ImportError` on an attempt of importing any package in `pkgnames`:

```
class PackageDiscarder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pkgnames = []
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname in self.pkgnames:
            raise ImportError()


@pytest.fixture
def no_requests():
    sys.modules.pop('requests', None)
    d = PackageDiscarder()
    d.pkgnames.append('requests')
    sys.meta_path.insert(0, d)
    yield
    sys.meta_path.remove(d)


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def cleanup_imports():
    yield
    sys.modules.pop('mypackage', None)


def test_requests_available():
    import mypackage
    assert mypackage.requests_available


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('no_requests2')
def test_requests_missing():
    import mypackage
    assert not mypackage.requests_available
```

The fixture `no_requests` will alter `sys.meta_path` when invoked, so the custom meta path finder filters out the `requests` package name from the ones that can be imported  (we can't raise on any import or `pytest` itself will break). `cleanup_imports` is just to ensure that `mypackage` will be reimported in each test.

#### Mocking `__import__`

```
import builtins
import sys
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def no_requests(monkeypatch):
    import_orig = builtins.__import__
    def mocked_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level):
        if name == 'requests':
            raise ImportError()
        return import_orig(name, locals, fromlist, level)
    monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, '__import__', mocked_import)


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def cleanup_imports():
    yield
    sys.modules.pop('mypackage', None)


def test_requests_available():
    import mypackage
    assert mypackage.requests_available


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('no_requests')
def test_requests_missing():
    import mypackage
    assert not mypackage.requests_available
```

Here, the fixture `no_requests` is responsible for replacing the `__import__` function with one that will raise on `import requests` attempt, doing fine on the rest of imports.

Comment: This works on both 3.5 and 3.6 and is much more specific than my old code.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_without_dependency(self):
    with patch.dict(sys.modules, {'optional_dependency': None}):
        # do whatever you want
```

What the above code does is, it mocks that the package `optional_dependency` is not installed and runs your test in that isolated environment inside the context-manager(`with`).

Keep in mind, you may have to reload the `module` under test depending upon your use case

```py
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch
from importlib import reload

def test_without_dependency(self):
    with patch.dict(sys.modules, {'optional_dependency': None}):
        reload(sys.modules['my_module_under_test'])
        # do whatever you want
```

Comment: This method works well and is also being in a similar manner in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65163627/8931942

Answer (score 2):

If a test tests optional functionality, it should be skipped rather than passed if that functionality is missing.

[`test.support.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html?highlight=import_module#test.support.import_module) is the function used in the Python autotest suite to skip a test or a test file if a module is missing:

```
import test.support
import unittest

nonexistent = test.support.import_module("nonexistent")

class TestDummy(unittest.testCase):
    def test_dummy():
        self.assertTrue(nonexistent.vaporware())
```

Then, when running:

```
> python -m py.test -rs t.py

<...>
collected 0 items / 1 skipped

=========================== short test summary info ===========================
SKIP [1] C:\Python27\lib\test\support\__init__.py:90: SkipTest: No module named
nonexistent
========================== 1 skipped in 0.05 seconds ==========================
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree. My intention is not to run alternative tests in case requests is avalable, but to test that mypackage do in case this module is not installed.