# Test behavior of code if optional module is not installed

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a software package, `packageA`, which has an optional dependency on `packageB`. If `packageB` is installed, then the user has access to some additional functionality. But, not having it installed does not limit the use of `packageA`.

I want to write a unit (or integration?) test that checks `packageA` is still usable if `packageB` is not installed... that is, it won't unexpectedly throw an `ImportError` for `packagB`

The test I have is written like this:

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest


def test_no_err_if_packageb_not_installed():
    import sys
    sys.modules['packageB'] = mock.MagicMock()
    try:
        from packageA import file_that_uses_packageb  # noqa: F401
    except NameError:
        pytest.fail("packagB dependency found at root level")
```

And this works, if it's called in isolation. But when it's called as part of the testing suite, this test will always pass. This is because `sys.modules` will already have been populated with the import modules by previous tests. I've tried to `del` the package from `sys.modules` first, but this doesn't work

What is the correct way to write this test?

**Edit with working solution**

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest


def test_no_err_if_packageb_not_installed():
    import sys

    # clear cached modules
    mods = list(sys.modules.keys())
    for mod in mods:
        if 'packageA' in mod or 'packageB' in mod:
            del sys.modules[mod]

    sys.modules['packageB'] = mock.MagicMock()
    try:
        from packageA import file_that_uses_packageb  # noqa: F401
    except NameError:
        pytest.fail("packagB dependency found at root level")

    del sys.modules['packageB']
```

Comment: You can also mock the `__import__` magic for the specific test, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51048604/2650249) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacking with `sys.modules` for this is the way to go. The problem is that you are reseting the import of `packageB` - but actually, to make this test, you have also to reset the import of `file_that_uses_packageb`.

In your test setup try `del sys.modules["packageB"], sys.modules["packageA.file_that_uses_packageB"]` and you should be all set.

Don't forget to reset those again at the end of your test, or other tests actually using `packageB` will fail.

(the answer that was temptativelly marked as  "duplicate" answer does not touch the same points -the answer talks about using `imp.reload`, which resets and re-runs a module, ok - but won't allow you to replace a modules code with mocks if needed)

Comment: yes - I had lost some editing, as I had to move back and forth tabs to reopen the prematurelly closed question.  I think it is all there now.

Comment: Thank you, I had to screw around with it a bit to get it to work, but this was the right idea. In the end, I didn't have to reset the deleted packages. Python seemed to just reload them. Will edit my quesiton with my working solution